# Continuous functions equal except on a nowhere dense set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

Consider two continuous functions $f,g : \mathbb{R} \supset I \to \mathbb{R}^k$ for which every subinterval $J \subset I$ contains a subinterval $K \subset J$ such that $\forall t \in K, f(t) = g(t)$.

Is it then true that $\forall t \in I \setminus E, f(t) = g(t)$ where $E$ is a nowhere dense subset of $I$? If so, can you point me to a solid reference?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is that for all $t\in J$ for all intervals $J\subset I$, or is J any subset of I?

Comment: That's a great question. I've updated the question to hopefully answer your question.

Comment: Your weird notation $f,g:\mathbb R\supset I\to\mathbb R^k$ means, I guess, that $f,g:I\to\mathbb R^k$ for some interval $I\subset\mathbb R$?

Comment: Let me get this straight. Let $E=\{t\in I:f(t)\ne g(t)\}$. Your hypothesis is that for every subinterval $J\subset I$ there is a subinterval $K\subset J$ which is disjoint from $E$? In other words, that $E$ is a nowhere dense subset of $I$? Is that it?

Comment: @bof, Yes, your characterization is more clear, and I now see that it is the same as Characterization #6  on the Wikipedia page for nowhere dense sets. Thank you for helping me see this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a reference for this, but it's a relatively straightforward application of the definition of a nowhere dense set. That's just to say that I wouldn't necessarily expect to find this recorded in a textbook somewhere, but I'll freely admit I haven't checked.

Here's the proof. To begin, let $\mathcal{J}$ be the collection of all open intervals $J \subseteq I$ where $f \equiv g$ on $J$. Letting $U = \bigcup_{J \in \mathcal{J}} J$, we have that $U$ is open, and $f \equiv g$ on $U$. Now let $F = I \setminus U$, so that $F$ is closed in $I$. Evidently $F$ contains the set $E = \{ t \in I : f(t) \neq g(t) \}$, so the closure of $E$ in $I$ is contained in $F$. As a result, to show that $E$ is nowhere dense it suffices to show that $F$ contains no (non-degenerate) interval.

This follows almost at once from the hypotheses: if $J'$ were an interval contained in $F$, we know there's a sub-interval $K \subseteq J'$ where $f \equiv g$. So then the interior of $K$ is actually in $U$, contradicting it being a part of $F$.

Comment: @bof I suppose I was starting from a slightly different, though of course equivalent, definition: that a set is nowhere dense if its closure has empty interior. I can delete the answer if it seems to cloud things more than illuminate, though.

Comment: No, don't. The OP does not say what definition of "nowhere dense" he's familiar with, he should clear that up. If he's using a definition like you mentioned, that would explain his difficulty with the question.

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the answer. You used the definition of nowhere dense that I was familiar with. After the discussion between you and bof, I see that his rephrasing of my question leads to a proof by definition.